# AttributeError: type object 'PartialDependenceDisplay' has no attribute 'from_estimator'

Tags: scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I'm trying to implement Partial Dependence Plot using the following example:

```
from sklearn.inspection import PartialDependenceDisplay
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
X, y = make_friedman1()
est1 = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
est2 = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X, y)
disp1 = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(est1, X,
                                                [1, 2])
disp2 = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(est2, X, [1, 2],
                                                ax=disp1.axes_)
```

But I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e98f23dac323> in <module>
      6 est1 = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
      7 est2 = RandomForestRegressor().fit(X, y)
----> 8 disp1 = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(est1, X,
      9                                                 [1, 2])
     10 disp2 = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(est2, X, [1, 2],

AttributeError: type object 'PartialDependenceDisplay' has no attribute 'from_estimator'
```

Is there any solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: That method is new in v1.0; do you have that version?

Comment: I used pip install sklearn --upgrade  to get the latest version and I get v0.21.3 not v1.0. How can I get v1.0? Thanks

Comment: I think it is pip install scikit-learn --upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue (Windows 10, Python 3.9.7 on Anaconda).
Issue resolved with upgrade sklearn package

```
 !pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```